# Ansible IP address variable - host part

Tags: shell, variables, ip, ansible

I have the following problem:

I'm writing playbook for setting IP address on the command line in Ansible. Lets say 10.10.10.x. I need to get the last part of my public IP lets say x.x.x.15 and assign it to the private: 10.10.10.15. Is there a variable for this? Can i capture some? I've tried to use something like:

```
shell: "ip addr show | grep inet ...." 
register: host_ip
```

But it is not what i need. It works, but only for a limited number of servers.

The whole thing should be like that:

```
"shell: /dir/script --options 10.10.10.{{ var }}"
```

and `{{ var }}` should be the host part of the public IP.

**Edit:**

Thank you! Here's my final solution:

```
- name: Get the host part of the IP 
  shell: host {{ ansible_fqdn }} | awk '{print $4}' 
  register: host_ip
```

And

```
{{ host_ip.stdout.split('.')[3] }}
```

For using it later in the playbook.

Comment: As per @user24364's answer below, it's not clear if your servers have public IP already assigned, or if you are going through a NAT router. Please update our question to clarify this situation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of using a system utility you can use ansible [facts](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) though you will find that interface names will vary from server to server.

You specifically mentioned the *last part of my public IP*

If you really mean your ***public IP*** you will need to use an external service to get it since your server may behind a NAT. Here is one option

```
shell: wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo
register: host_ip
```

That will give your public IP, next to get the last octet you could do something like:

```
{{ host_ip.stdout.split('.')[3] }}
```

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned by jarv this can be obtained by using [facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts).

This can be done in the following ways:

For a list of all ipv4 addresses:

```
{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }}
```

For the default ipv4 address:

```
{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
```

If you know the ip address is on the eth0 interface:

```
{{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
```

You can then append the `.split('.')[3]` method to the variable to get the appropriate output, for example `{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address.split('.')[3] }}`

Answer (score 0):

This is an similar way to get it:

```
- name: Get the local IP
  local_action:
      module: uri
      url: http://checkip.amazonaws.com/
      return_content: yes
  register: ip_lookup
- set_fact:
      local_ip: "{{ ip_lookup.content | regex_replace('\n','') }}"
- debug: var=local_ip
```